# db password problem

Tags: database, error-message

i've got this error:

> [error] [exception.CDbException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd
>   cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication.
>   Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the
>   command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will
>   store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user
>   is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need
>   to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file

i've already set a new password in the webspace, but the error is the same.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: If someone has the same problem. Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication

Comment: Can you add that as an official answer?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, would you mind either accepting Ben's answer (if that solved the problem) or adding your own here and accepting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was solved via the related question on Stack Overflow here: [Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576473/1586560)